# dialog box in a map android

Tags: android, xml, dictionary

i want to create a dialog box when the map get start .. i create this code on my maps activity but i don t know how to make it work what i m missing  !thank you

this is my full code for the activity where i show the map

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LatLng origin, dest;
String name, name1;
ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
TextView ShowDistanceDuration;
Polyline line;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
#.......

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for position
    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin);

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for zoom
    CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(4);

    // Updating the camera position to the user input latitude and longitude
    googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);

    // Applying zoom to the marker position
    googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);

    Button btnDriving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDriving);
    btnDriving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            build_retrofit_and_get_response("driving");
        }
    });

    Button btnWalk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWalk);
    btnWalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            build_retrofit_and_get_response("walking");
        }
    });
}

private void addMarker(GoogleMap googleMap, LatLng position, String name) {
    // Instantiating MarkerOptions class
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting position for the MarkerOptions
    options.position(position);

    // Setting title for the MarkerOptions
    options.title(name);

    // Setting snippet for the MarkerOptions
    options.snippet("Latitude:"+position.latitude+",Longitude:"+position.longitude)

    googleMap.addMarker(options);
}
    // *****************for the dialog  to change map*********//

private static final CharSequence[] MAP_TYPE_ITEMS =
        {"Road Map", "Hybrid", "Satellite", "Terrain"};

private void showMapTypeSelectorDialog() {
    // Prepare the dialog by setting up a Builder.
    final String fDialogTitle = "Select Map Type";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(fDialogTitle);

    // Find the current map type to pre-check the item representing the 
 current state.
    int checkItem = mMap.getMapType() - 1;

    // Add an OnClickListener to the dialog, so that the selection will be 
handled.
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
            MAP_TYPE_ITEMS,
            checkItem,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    // Locally create a finalised object.

                    // Perform an action depending on which item was 
 selected.
                    switch (item) {
                        case 1:
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                            break;
                        default:
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );

    // Build the dialog and show it.
    AlertDialog fMapTypeDialog = builder.create();
    fMapTypeDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    fMapTypeDialog.show();
  }

 }
```

Comment: don t know how to collect it with my xml activity......... what does it mean?

Comment: i think i nedd to creact a file xml named"dialog box" for example and call it in this activity? no?

Comment: Seems your codes are ok for dialog with single choice item. Why need dialogbox xml?

Comment: Can you please give a design of your dialog?

Comment: to be honnest i m new with this stuf..i thought that an xml file is missing...

Comment: so why it does not work?

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: no the map is appear without any error ..:(

Comment: when you call showMapTypeSelectorDialog() isn't it showing dialog?

Comment: map is appear without any error........ that means its working??

Comment: so i must call it? where? really i don t understund.. what i khnow is that code will create the box dialog and when  my map appear a box dialog will appear to ..

Comment: yes my map it s working good

Comment: can you please post your full code?

Comment: okk wait ... thnks

Comment: Post your activity class

Comment: ok i edit my question this is my full code

Comment: Ferdous Ahamed what do you think?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `Button` in your `activity_maps.xml` file and use this `Button` to change map type by call method `showMapTypeSelectorDialog()`.

**Update `onMapReady()` as below:**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for position
    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin);

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for zoom
    CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(4);

    // Updating the camera position to the user input latitude and longitude
    googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);

    // Applying zoom to the marker position
    googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);

    Button btnDriving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDriving);
    btnDriving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            build_retrofit_and_get_response("driving");
        }
    });

    Button btnWalk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWalk);
    btnWalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            build_retrofit_and_get_response("walking");
        }
    });

    Button btnChangeMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeMap);
    btnChangeMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Show map selection dialog
            showMapTypeSelectorDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

**Add below `Button` to `activity_maps.xml`**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeMap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Map"/>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: that wooorkkk :D :D i just will change it to setting menu better than a boutton i have much button on the map 
thnkkkks

Comment: Happy to know that. If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just another thing plz..if i use the menu .. i will change button in mapready by what?